# NSArrayController NSTableView Core Data Binding integers

Tags: core-data, nstableview, nsarraycontroller, nstablecellview

I have an NSTableView bound to an NSArrayController, which in turn is bound to Core Data. The table displays integer values from core data nicely, but if I edit the numbers in the table I get an error:

```
Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "armorclass"; desired type = NSNumber; given type = NSTaggedPointerString; value = 10.
```

Any suggestions of how I can convert this pointer string back to an Int16 before the Array Controller tries to save it back to Core Data?

I wrote the following ValueTransformer but it's not working properly. I always get the error: Cannot find value transformer with name StringIntegerValueTransformer

```
class StringIntegerValueTransformer: ValueTransformer {

    override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass { //What do I transform
        return String.self as! AnyClass
    }

    override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool { //Can I transform back?
        return false
    }

    override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        if let val = value {
            return String(describing: val)
        }
        return "nil"
    }

    override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? { //Revert transformation
        if let val = value {
            return val as? Int16
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

fff

Answer (score 1):

To register the value transformer override `init` in `AppDelegate`

```
override init()
{
   let stringIntegerValueTransformer = StringIntegerValueTransformer()
   ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(stringIntegerValueTransformer, forName:NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: "StringIntegerValueTransformer"))
   super.init()
 }
```

And consider this note from the documentation

> Your NSValueTransformer subclasses are not automatically listed in the Interface Builder bindings inspector. When inspecting a binding you can enter the name that the value transformer is registered with, but the functionality will not be present in Interface Builder’s test mode. When your application is compiled and run the transformer will be used

Answer (score 0):

Add a number formatter to the text field.